# IOS - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uistoryboard, uipageviewcontroller

Hello I am implementing a tutorial screen on IOS so I am using PageViewController. I am following this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnC8XVdHsVM

the tutorial code can be found here

https://github.com/simplyi/UIPageVIewControllerExample

when I run the app this error comes

**"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"**

The program is stopping here at this line

**TutorialScreenViewController.swift**

```
var imageFileName: String!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


  myImageView.image = UIImage(named:imageFileName)
   }
```

In another controller name **ViewController.swift** I am doing this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            pageImages = NSArray(objects: "startscreen","startscreen2","startscreen3")


            self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

            self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

            let initialContenViewController = self.pageTutorialAtIndex(0) as TutorialScreenViewController

            let viewControllers = NSArray(object: initialContenViewController)

            self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
           /* self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)*/

            self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-100)

            self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
            self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
            self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        }
  func pageTutorialAtIndex(index: Int) -> TutorialScreenViewController
    {

        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TutorialScreenViewController") as! TutorialScreenViewController

        pageContentViewController.imageFileName = pageImages[index] as! String
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index


        return pageContentViewController

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {

        let viewController = viewController as! TutorialScreenViewController
        var index = viewController.pageIndex as Int

        if(index == 0 || index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

        index--

        return self.pageTutorialAtIndex(index)

    }

     func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

     {
        let viewController = viewController as! TutorialScreenViewController
        var index = viewController.pageIndex as Int

        if((index == NSNotFound))
        {
            return nil
        }

        index++

        if(index == pageImages.count)
        {
            return nil
        }

        return self.pageTutorialAtIndex(index)
    }



    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int

    {

    return pageImages.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.

    {
    return 0

    }
```

any one has any idea what is wrong with this line.

Comment: did you add the image named ImageFileName in your asset document ?

Comment: see I have updated the question. @kholl

Comment: assign the imagename(value) to imageFileName variable.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand. could you please edit that code which needs to be modified. I am sorry actually I  new in IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad you Have to set the var imageFileName: String! before using it

create a var like the ( var name : type!) means that you create an optional of type type and you set it to nil yet it can be accessed without having to unwrap it because of the ! and not ? , you never set the imageFileName !!

What you have to do is to set the imageFileName in viewDidLoad before using it :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
if imageFileName == nil {
imageFileName = "startscreen"
}
myImageView.image = UIImage(named:imageFileName)
}
```

Comment: in the github project the asset is not named startscreen but "screen1.jpg"

Comment: But there are three images ?

Comment: okay so you have to create three UIImage with the different names :-) . and change it  I don't know if that's clear for you but right now you create an image with the "startscreen" asset name and you assign it to myImageView.Image , if you want to assign another image you have to create another UIImage

Comment: okay Actually I am implementing  a tutorial screen... so three images will come from another controller. you can see above... if I try your code then app runs successfully and loads only one image and doesn't implement the tutorial screen functionality. seems like it doesn't go to another controller something like that

Comment: I updated my question again so you can have better understanding

Comment: yes It's because when you call .setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil) you create three time the same viewController , with the same image name , if you want to create three viewController with three different image you have to set the viewController property before giving it to the function but that's all your tutorial is about

Comment: that's another question and it's a full tutorial but you have to remember that a viewController is nothing else ut an object that can be init (let vc = viewController() ) with property that can be set ( vc. imageFileName = pageImages[2]) and your viewController array can be composed of object with different property this way . I'll edit my code for letting you set the property